# Compare dates in 2 column with same ID and find latest date

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I have 3 column 
A = ID
B = S_Provided
C = M_Provided

In column D, I would like to populate the newest/latest Date for given ID between B & C

**Here is Screenshot**
Formula I have in D2 is `=IF(A2=A1,D1,IF(B2>C2,B2,C2))` 
but this formula failed when `ID=81`. D should be `11/11/2012 4:15:00 PM`

[image]

Comment: Circulartory Reference of D1

Comment: @user2140261 Sorry I don't understand you, can you please explain. BTW just found solution posted.

Comment: in cell D1 `if(A2 = A1,D1)` you can't set a cell to equal itself.

Comment: Sorry, it should've been `D2` typo

Answer (score 0):

If anyone found better solution they are welcome to post it.

in Column D: with Ctrl+Shift+Enter

```
=MAX(IF(A2=$A$2:$A$999, $B$2:$C$999))
```

Reference
http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/12/05/lookup-a-value-and-find-max-date-in-excel/